# chi square independence in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, chi-squared

Can we do 'chi square independence' test using MATLAB? If yes, I am looking for a 'reliable' work example.
I have not tried any and I am not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use the function that can be found in file exchange: https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7143-chi-square-test-for-independence.

To perform the test just call función `chi2test(data, numOfInterval)` with your data and number of intervals.

### Example code

```
data = rand(1000, 1000);
num_int = 8;
chi2test(data, num_int);

x =
    5.6000

ans =
   14.0671
```

where `x` is the result of the chi-Square test of independence
and `ans` is the inverse of the chi-square cumulative distribution function with `num_int` degrees of freedom specified for the corresponding probabilities in `data`.

Please refer to [1] for further information about this function.

[1] Kevin Wong (2020). Chi Square Test for Independence (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7143-chi-square-test-for-independence), MATLAB Central File Exchange. Retrieved April 12, 2020.

Comment: can you post a results here too?

Comment: Hi @Mohammad. I have edited the answer to include an example with the results. I hope it helps you.